# Limiting the number of connections to a server

Tags: java, server

I have a multi-threaded server in Java, however I want to limit the number of connected clients to 2. It's a basic application, just being used for testing.

On my server I have an int userNo attribute that assigns clients the value of either 0 or 1.

My question is, is there a better way of handling this. I only want up to 2 clients to connect, and I want my application to ignore any further requests.

Pseduo code:

```
    if(userNo == 0) {
    this is player 1;
    }
    if (userNo == 1) {
    this is player 2;
    }
    else {
    do nothing
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
int connectedClientCount = 0;
// ...
while(true) {
    ServerSocket ss = ...
    Socket s = ss.accept();
    if(connectedClientCount == 2) {
        // Do stuff to tell connected Client that he is rejected because of max clients...
    } else {
        connectedClientCount++;
        // cool stuff...
    }
}
```

and somewhere else in you code (which gets executed on client disconnect)

```
public void clientDisconnected() {
    connectedClientCount--;
}
```

Because of sake of simplicity I don't use thread synchronization in this example..